# How to get first occurrence in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, break

I have XML data which has a structure like below. I need to fetch only first `CX.1` value which `CX.5` value starts with 'TN'

```
<PID.3.LST>
    <PID.3>
        <CX.1>432</CX.1>
        <CX.4>BH</CX.4>
        <CX.5>TN</CX.5>
        <CX.6>BH</CX.6>
    </PID.3>
    <PID.3>
        <CX.1>444</CX.1>
        <CX.4>BH</CX.4>
        <CX.5>TN</CX.5>
        <CX.6>BH</CX.6>
    </PID.3>
    <PID.3>
        <CX.1>8415</CX.1>
        <CX.4>SWH</CX.4>
        <CX.5>MR</CX.5>
        <CX.6>SWH</CX.6>
    </PID.3>
    <PID.3>
        <CX.1>915252936  </CX.1>
        <CX.2>9</CX.2>
        <CX.4>AUSHIC</CX.4>
        <CX.5>MC</CX.5>
    </PID.3>
</PID.3.LST>
```

I want to load only the first `CX.1` value which `CX.5` value contains 'TN'.

This is the XSLT code that I'm using, but it returns all `CX.1` values.

```
<xsl:variable name="UR" select="CX.5"/>
<xsl:if test="substring($UR,1,2)='TN'">
    My ID:  <xsl:variable name="URsub" select="substring-after('TN',$UR)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="CX.1"/>                                       
</xsl:if>
```

In another word, I need to break my for-each in XSLT

Answer (score 2):

> I need to fetch only first CX.1 value which CX.5 value starts with 'TN'

The matching expressing you are looking for is

```
//CX.1[starts-with(../CX.5,'TN')][1]
```

In a whole template this looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="//CX.1[starts-with(../CX.5,'TN')][1]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath will select the first `CX.1` element who's sibling `CX.5` element contains "TN":

```
(/PID.3.LST/PID.3[contains(CX.5,"TN")]/CX.1)[1]
```